# Android Vim (DroidVim?) keyboard with swipe functionality

Tags: keyboard-layout, user-input, input-methods, input-devices

I am wondering what it would take to build an Android keyboard that mimicked Vim, with swipe (swype?) functionality (such as the one Google's Gboard uses to allow users to write on Android).

This would be very useful to write tinkered Gists and code on Android devices (smartphones and tablets).

Has this in any way been done?

Is anyone willing to implement it?

Think of entering the `cw` command by swiping from c to w on the keyboard, and then entering text by swiping.

Swiping is an accessibility feature.

Comment: I really don’t understand what this question is asking, and I suspect it is off-topic (see [help/on-topic]). If this is about Vi/Vim as an editor, please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Not an answer but some years ago, I installed some Vim clone/app/whatever on my Android phone. It took me about ten seconds to realize that Vim without touch-typing just doesn't fly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such implementation but it seems difficult to do.

Swipe implementation rely on the interpolation of possible meaning from the gesture.

When you swipe fro `c` to `w` on a querty keyboard you will not cross anything else that one is easy but when you want to do `ciw` then you cross a number of other characters and to make the distinction in between all the possible Vim meanings it will become difficult.

Vim is designed to have very short command code and requires good typing skills. The beginner I was had a difficult time understanding the result of my small miss-typing and in the site we cross people that have the same kind of questions.

The swipe algorithm is fine with typing text the words are long enough and the context helps to precise further what the user probably wants but for Vim code that looks much more challenging to me.